# Same transaction returns different results when i ran multiply times

Tags: tidb

When i was using TiDB, I found it strange when i make two transactions run at the same time. I was expecting to get the the same value 2 like what MySQL did, but all i got is like 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2...

For both databases, the tx_isolation is set to 'read-committed'. So it is reasonable that the select statement returns 2 as it has already committed.

Here's the test code:

```
for i in range(10):
    conn1 = mysql.connector.connect(host='',
                                port=4000,
                                user='',
                                password='',
                                database='',
                                charset='utf8')
    conn2 = mysql.connector.connect(host='',
                                port=4000,
                                user='',
                                password='',
                                database='',
                                charset='utf8')

    cur1 = conn1.cursor()
    cur2 = conn2.cursor()

    conn1.start_transaction()
    conn2.start_transaction()

    cur2.execute("update t set b=%d where a=1" % 2)
    conn2.commit()

    cur1.execute("select b from t where a=1")
    a = cur1.fetchone()
    print(a)

    cur1.execute("update t set b=%d where a=1" % 0)
    conn1.commit()

    cur1.close()
    cur2.close()
    conn1.close()
    conn2.close()
```

The table t is created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `a` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `b` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`a`)
)
```

and (1,0) is inserted initially.

Answer (score 0):

### First of All:

> For **TiDB** only support **SNAPSHOT**(latest version)
>   **Transactions Isolation Level**. but it only can see **committed data** before **Transaction** started.
>
> and **TiDB** also will not **update the same value in transaction**,
>   like **MySQL** and **SQL Server** etc.
>
> For **MySQL**, when use the **READ COMMITTED** isolation level, it
>   will read **committed** data, so it will read the other transactions
>   committed data.

So as your code snippet:

**TiDB** **round 1** workflow:

```
               T1                                   T2

     +--------------------+
     | transaction start  |
     |      (b = 0)       |
     +---------+----------+
               |
               |
               |                        +------------------------------+
               | <----------------------+  update `b` to 2, and commit |
               |                        +------------------------------+
               |
               |
   +-----------+-----------+
   | select b should be 0, |
   | since tidb will only  |
   | get the data before   |
   | transaction committed |
   +-----------+-----------+
               |
               v

+------------------------------+
|      update value to 0       |
| (since 0 is equal to the     |
| transaction started value,   |
| tidb will ignore this update)|
+------------------------------+
                                  +
                                  |
                                  |
                                  |
                                  v

                      +-------------------------+
                      |so finally `b` will be 2 |
                      +-------------------------+
```

**TiDB round 2** workflow:

```
               T1                                   T2

     +--------------------+
     | transaction start  |
     |      (b = 2)       |
     +---------+----------+
               |
               |
               |                        +------------------------------+
               | <----------------------+  update `b` to 2, and commit |
               |                        +------------------------------+
               |
               |
   +-----------+-----------+
   | select b should be 2, |
   | since tidb will only  |
   | get the data before   |
   | transaction committed |
   +-----------+-----------+
               |
               v

+------------------------------+
|      update value to 0       |
| (since 0 is not equal to 2   |
+------------------------------+
                                  +
                                  |
                                  |
                                  |
                                  v

                      +-------------------------+
                      |so finally `b` will be 0 |
                      +-------------------------+
```

So for **TiDB** will output like:

```
0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2...
```

**MySQL** workflow:

```
                      T1                                   T2


          +----------------------+
          |  transaction start   |
          |       ( b = 0 )      |
          +-----------+----------+
                      |
                      |
                      |
                      |                         +---------------------------+
                      |  <----------------------+update `b` to 2, and commit|
                      |                         +---------------------------+
                      |
                      |
                      v

+--------------------------------------------+
| select b should be 2,                      |
| since use READ COMMITTED isolation level,  |
| it will read committed data.               |
+---------------------+----------------------+
                      |
                      |
                      v

           +--------------------+
           | update value to 0  |
           +--------------------+
                                        +
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        v

                             +--------------------------+
                             | so finally `b` will be 0 |
                             +--------------------------+
```

so **MySQL** can continuously output:

`2, 2, 2, 2...`

---

### Last of word

I think this is very strange for **TiDB** to **skip the update same value** in **Transaction**, but when with the **different value** it also can be updated success, like we can update `b` to different value in the loop, we always can get the **latest changed** b.

So maybe it should be better keep same behavior between **same value** and **different value**.

I have created a issue for this:

https://github.com/pingcap/tidb/issues/7644

References:

https://github.com/pingcap/docs/blob/master/sql/transaction-isolation.md